# Is there chance to catch all executed query

Tags: php, sql

Hi is there any chance to cache all executed query on site? without any class which will execute and write it to array?

I need to write some script which will show me all executed query on the bottom of my page. Now I use Kohana and its simple becouse there is profiler class which shows that, but what with simple `mysql_query`?

Comment: The mysql_* functions don't have a native way of doing this...

Answer (score 0):

An ugly, but simple and effective way of doing it:

```
function mysql_query_log ($query, $conn = NULL) {
  if (!isset($GLOBALS['__QueryLog'])) $GLOBALS['__QueryLog'] = array();
  $GLOBALS['__QueryLog'][] = $query;
  return mysql_query($query, $conn);
}
```

Change all of your calls to `mysql_query()` to `mysql_query_log()`, and the global variable `$__QueryLog` is an array of all the queries that have been executed so far.

The reason I call this an "ugly" method is that the function modifies variables outside it's own scope, which is bad practice and should be avoided. But for simplicity, this can't be beat.